# Как получить текущую скорость движения (скорость передвижения по местности)

Tags: android, gps

Как корректнее всего получить текущую скорость в приложении для Android?

Answer (score 1):

Не могу оставить комментарий, посмотрите по этой ссылке: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570542/determining-the-speed-of-a-vehicle-using-gps-in-android

Достаточно хорошо разобрали вопрос.

Comment: ссылка на en.so, возможно многим будет более полезен Ваш ответ, если Вы вставите в него основное из ссылки с переводом на русский и/или со своими пояснениями.

Answer (score 1):

У класса [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) есть метод [getSpeed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed()), используйте его.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this 
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        location.getLatitude();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Скорость:" + location.getSpeed(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

}; 

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```